# CosmosDB - Comment System Model

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure and trying their CosmosDB for a commenting system. In the documents it recommends a commenting system be modelled something like this:

```
Post item:
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "What's new in the coolest Cloud",
    "summary": "A blog post by someone real famous",
    "recentComments": [
        {"id": 1, "author": "anon", "comment": "something useful, I'm sure"},
        {"id": 2, "author": "bob", "comment": "wisdom from the interwebs"},
        {"id": 3, "author": "jane", "comment": "....."}
    ]
}

Comment items:
{
    "postId": "1"
    "comments": [
        {"id": 4, "author": "anon", "comment": "more goodness"},
        {"id": 5, "author": "bob", "comment": "tails from the field"},
        ...
        {"id": 99, "author": "angry", "comment": "blah angry blah angry"}
    ]
},
{
    "postId": "1"
    "comments": [
        {"id": 100, "author": "anon", "comment": "yet more"},
        ...
        {"id": 199, "author": "bored", "comment": "will this ever end?"}
    ]
}
```

For the Post collection, I understand the "id" would be a good partition key and I understand how I would insert and query this item.

I am lost with how I would insert and query the comments in terms of syntax and logic. For the Comment collection:

- What would be the partition key?
- If a user wants to post a new comment, how (logic and syntax) would I
  know which item to insert it into and how would I know if the array
  is full and if I'd have to create a new item if the 100 limit was
  reached?
- In regards to the previous question, how would this work with two
  users adding a comment at the same time (transaction)? If the first
  user fills the last space of the 100 limit, how does the comment
  coming from the second user know that it needs to insert into a new
  item?
- If I need to delete item 50 in the middle of the array, how would I readjust all the comments to fit in the proper arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a very broad set of questions, and there's no "right" answer to this (plus you've asked several questions, not one). One thing to keep in mind regarding your schema (and your second bullet): you have an "unbounded array" condition - there's nothing preventing unlimited comments (until you run out of room in a single document). And trying to "create a new item" is not an ideal solution (you're building your own linked-list, essentially). I'd spend some time thinking about how you might arrange this better. (also not sure what "100 limit" you're referring to).

Comment: @DavidMakogon This is the model from the official azure documentation how they recommend a comment system to be modeled.

Comment: There's no single way to model a commenting system. I have no idea what docs you're referring to, as there is no link. Maybe it was written to serve as an example? I pointed out a real-world limitation to that model (there are other issues as well, such as the constant need to read/update/write a single blog document every time you add/edit/remove a comment, and the need to carry all that extra weight around when all you want is the post with no comments). This is but one example of why this question is off-topic: very broad. The modeling choice will be dependent on your app, query needs, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data. I want to do basically the same thing described in the docs. I need to insert comments under a post, and I need to get the comments for a post in batches of N

Comment: Please re-read that page: it explicitly calls out the *unbounded array* issue with storing comments that way, and then suggests an alternative model. As for what you want to insert: I suggest starting with a new question, specific to your issue of inserting. Show what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected vs actual output, errors, etc. I really don't know what else to say at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We definitely do not recommend modeling your data this way.

Unbounded arrays should never be embedded. Please see this [How to model and partition data on Azure Cosmos DB using a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Thanks.

Comment: Might as well just post this as a comment, as there's simply no way to answer this objectively. Plus they've asked a batch of questions, and haven't really shown any specific question for any (just "how do I do this" which is considered off-topic). And I've tried to explain this many different ways. I even pointed out that the article the OP tried actually calls out the issue with unbounded arrays.